# How to recompile Python2.7 with 4-byte unicode enabled?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, compilation

I have tried `./configure --enable-unicode` and `./configure --enable-unicode=ucs4` but the command `import sys; print sys.maxunicode` is still 65535.

How should I fix this and compile Python with 4-byte unicode enabled?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the output of

```
./configure --help
```

the correct option is given as

```
--enable-unicode=ucs4
```

Comment: Sorry for the typo, the actual option I used is `--enable-unicode=ucs4`, the code in the question has been corrected.

Comment: After another try, the installation works. This option is indeed the solution.

Answer (score 2):

We can re-compile already installed python with 4-byte Unicode or 2-byte Unicode

Full Flow
after downloading python2.7.x and extracting it.

1. go to directory Python2.7.x (in my case it is Python2.7.10)

2.fire command "sudo ./configure --enable-unicode=ucs4" or "sudo ./configure --enable-unicode=ucs2" which ever you want.

now you can check if it is UCS2 or UCS4 as below
1.go to terminal

2.type **python** and enter
now enter following commands

> > > import sys
> > >       print sys.maxunicode

if output is **1114111** then it is UCS4 
otherwise if output is **65535** then it is UCS2